# repeating functions just changing one var

Tags: php, jquery

This is what i have, and it works but i wonder if it could be easier?

```
$('.item1').click(function(){
    $('.otheritem').animtate('left':'0');
});
$('.item2').click(function(){
    $('.otheritem').animtate('left':'100');
});
$('.item3').click(function(){
    $('.otheritem').animtate('left':'200');
});
// etc etc etc
```

I have a file that uses php foreach and generates a couple of items.

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $i++;
    echo "<a class='item$i item' href='#'>$i</a>";
}
```

So the more images the more items, so if you click on one of the items generated by the php it will determine the position of  .otheritem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could embed the changing value inside a data property on the element, and just give all the elements the same selector -

```
$animLeft = $i * 100;
echo "<a class='item' href='#' data-animleft='{$animLeft}' >$i</a>";
```

Now your jQuery can access all of the elements by the same name and extract the value for the animation :

```
$('.item').on('click',function(){
  var animateValue = $(this).data('animleft');
  $('.otheritem').animtate('left':animateValue);
});
```

References -

- [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Thanks @chad :P This is also my 1000th answer! **WOO HOO!**

Comment: It worked! Had to change my php a bit so it generates the data-animleft. but it worked perfectly with the jquery. Thank u

Answer (score 2):

If all items are fixed width, you can calculate the position based on it's position in the list.

e.g.

```
$('.buttons').click( function() {
    $('.otheritem').animate('left', $(this).index() * 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.otheritem').animate('left', i * 100);
    });
});
```